# Java SSLSocket with Socks5 Proxy

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, socks

How can I use a SSLSocket with a socks5 proxy? I use a normal socket with proxy as underlying.

This code does not work:

```
public void debugIP(Proxy proxy) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
      sslContext.init(null, null, null);

      Socket underlying = new Socket(proxy);
      InetSocketAddress proxyAddress = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address();

      underlying.connect(new InetSocketAddress("checkip.amazonaws.com", 80));

      SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(
              underlying,
              proxyAddress.getHostName(),
              proxyAddress.getPort(),
              true);

      printInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
  }

  private void printInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

      String line;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
      }
  }
```

This code is throwing exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Without SSL the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking SSL to a plaintext port.

Just as the error message says.

Either fix the port or don't use SSL.

Comment: And if you do use SSL, give that `createSocket` overload (per Javadoc) the hostname and port for 'the logical peer destination' i.e. the target not the proxy.